# how to change the uibutton image three times when clicked

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

How can I change the image of the `UIButton` three times and also get the state or set a value that later i can use as my reference.

**For example**, The initial image of `UIButton` is white when first click it will turn to yellow then third clicked it will be green then if its green and clicked again it will return to white. i also need to set a value from different states.

And this will be applied to 10 individual 'UIButton'.

**Scenario**, UIButton will be used to display the state of the watches, initial value is white which mean -new when clicked it will turn to yellow which mean used and when clicked again it will turn to green which mean first class watch.
just a sample scenario only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
-(void) buttonPressed: (id) sender {
     if([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
         UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
         if(button.backgroundColor == [UIColor White])
             button.backgroundColor = [UIColor Yellow];
         else if(button.backgroundColor == [UIColor Yellow])
             button.backgroundColor = [UIColor Green];
         else if(button.backgroundColor == [UIColor Green])
             button.backgroundColor = [UIColor White];
     }
}
```

havnt tested that at all, but something along those lines should work. treat this as pseudo code

Comment: nice!, will do this and let you know, but the solution is very clear thank you for the hint

Comment: mm one problem is keeping a reference for the state of the particular button, you can just keep a reference to each of the buttons and check their color to tell what state they are in. not a very elegant solution...

Comment: 'UIButton *button = (UIButton)sender;' should i place a * in UIButton sender?